# Google API AndroidPublisher does not return reviews

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using Googles official .NET library to access the reviews of my app (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/list is the corresponding API)

```
"Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v2": "1.16.0.594"
```

This is (roughly) my code:

```
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("client_email_from_service_account_json"
    {
        Scopes = new[] { AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher }
    }.FromPrivateKey("private_key_from_service_account_json"));

var service = new AndroidPublisherService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "some_name",
});

var request = service.Reviews.List("my_app_id");

using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.ExecuteAsStream()))
{
    var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // json is only "{}\n"
}

var requestResult = await request.ExecuteAsync();
// requestResult.Reviews is null
```

I get the same (empty) result when I take the `access_token` from `credential` and to the `HTTP GET` call manually.

There is no error, so access should be working correctly - but I only ever get an empty JSON object.

When I try to access a specific review via its ID, it works fine (again, not pointing to an access problem).

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/589 the reviews API only returns reviews posted in the last 7 days.